# Xubuntu fails to boot after update

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I'm posting on behalf of a friend who had trouble booting after updating from Xubuntu 16.04 to 17.10. Because they no longer have a computer to post from, I'm posting instead. Anyways they wrote this to me in a text message:

"It's been prompting me for a general update for roughly 2 weeks, but every time I tried to let it, it failed. Then two days ago, it prompted for a complete updated. Obviously, I said yes, it downloaded within 2 hours then rebooted. When it came back up, it's got a slightly darker blue xubuntu screen and lets me to the decryption screen. After it's decrypted, it goes to a black screen with a blinking white cursor in the top left of the screen and sits like that."

Does anyone have any ideas on how to help them?

Comment: With this Information,I can tell Something is So  bad, cause **(1)**  17.10 is NOT RELEASED yet. **(2)** It is NOT POSSIBLE TO UPGRADE 16.04 TO 17.10 directly.you have to upgrade to first 16.10 then to 17.04 and then 17.10 which is not released yet.

Comment: So how do we fix this?

Comment: Install new and clean Xubuntu as Last resort if no one answers this question.